# How to fire triggers on the Views in MySql

Tags: mysql

I want to create one trigger on the view named as 'AccountView'. So how can I change the value of View on INSERT operation because I don't want to play with my base table.
 I am having Base table name as account having only one column (amount int).

```
CREATE TRIGGER check_trigger BEFORE INSERT ON AccountView
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF New.amount < 100 then
SET New.amount = 130;
END;
```

Please help!

Comment: Not possible in MySQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do it. The MySQL [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-trigger.html) says:

> You cannot associate a trigger with a TEMPORARY table or a view.